# How is my understand of this sentence?

Tags: meaning, syntax, sentence

やっぱりゆきのさんにはもったいないな

I think it means 'You are not worthy of Yukino-san'

Is this correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

「ゆきのさんにはもったいない」 would be "(Someone/something) is too good for Yukino-san" → "Yukino-san is not worthy (of someone/something)".

"You are not worthy of Yukino-san" would be 「ゆきのさんはあなたにはもったいない」, "Yukino-san is too good for you."

Comment: だ～　This is so confusing....